# ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'pango-1.0-0' UBUNTU SERVER (EC2)

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04, weasyprint

I am setting up my EC2 instance on AWS with an UBUNTU 18.04 and running into the following error when trying to run this gunicorn command `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 zipherJobCards.wsgi:application`

error:

```
OSError: cannot load library 'pango-1.0-0': pango-1.0-0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.  
Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'pango-1.0-0'
```

I ran into this error after installing weasyprint in both my base directory and my web apps directory.

Does anyone know the cause of this and also how to fix it?

Answer (score 9):

I got a similar error and after installing this solved the problem

**sudo apt-get install -y libpangocairo-1.0-0**

Answer (score 2):

For mac, I just installed `pango` using homebrew and it seemed to work.

Ran `brew install pango`

Relevant link: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pango